# How to config log4j2.xml to log to multiple files?

Tags: logging, mule

Here I am trying to configure log4j2.xml file so that it can be logging to 2 files, please see the config below. However I only get one log file **integrated_application.log**, the other log file **my_application.log** is not logging at all. Did I miss any configuration? or, Shall I add another AsyncRoot? Thanks for your help!

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}my_application.log" filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}my_application-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}integrated_applications.log" filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}integrated_applications-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services-->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN" />
    <!--Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log-->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
    <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="WARN" />
    <!-- Mule classes -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO" />
    <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO"/>
    <!-- Reduce DM verbosity -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.jetel" level="WARN" />
    <AsyncLogger name="Tracking" level="WARN" />

    <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </AsyncRoot>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change names of `RollingFile` as `file1` and `file2`. Use this in `AppenderRef` as

```
<AsyncRoot level="INFO">
    <AppenderRef ref="file1" />
    <AppenderRef ref="file2" />
</AsyncRoot>
```

Hope this helps.